# Error con función input en spyder 5.1.5

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

Quisiera saber a que se debe este error y como podría solucionarlo. Antes tenía una versión más antigua de Spyder, estos días la actualicé y demás todo a la última versión, que es la 5.1.5.

Una vez me puse a programar, al ejecutar la función input me da el siguiente error, os pongo un ejemplo:

```
peso=float(input('¿Cuanto pesa?'))
```

Y al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se podría solucionar este problema? ¿Es algo de la nueva versión? Ya que antes podía ejecutarlo sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolver el error en Ubuntu 20.04. 4 de la siguiente manera:

1. Abril una terminal y ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

conda create -n spyder-env spyder -c conda-forge

2. Después el siguiente comando:

conda create -n spyder-env spyder numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython -c conda-forge

3. Finalmente, activar el nuevo environment:
   conda activate spyder-env

Ejecuta spyder y la función input me funcionó bien.

Te dejo algunos enlaces que me ayudaron para encontrar la solución

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17616

https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html